# How do I get the value of fields in a template?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have created a custom template for a view called, say, "Example":

```
views-view-fields--example--page.html.twig
```

This works fine. I can display the title of each item in the template thus:

```
{{ fields.title.content }}
```

Also works fine. However, I've been unable to work out how to display the individual fields in my content type. How do I do that?

Comment: use dump() function to print out the variables. Ensure that you have turned on the debug mode from services.yml file.

Comment: That's using PHP. This is within a Twig template.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1906780)

Comment: you'll have to implement preprocess hook.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in my template was very helpful:

```
<ol>
{% for key, value in _context  %}
  <li>{{ key }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

From here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1906780